# Constant output program

Tags: code-challenge, popularity-contest

I was wondering how one might go and produce a program that takes input from some kind of random source and uses it to produce constant output. An obvious way is, for example, to take an integer x and output x/x for 1, but that isn't too clever, is it? Therefore, the task is to write a program that outputs the same thing, no matter which input is given to it.

**Specifications**

- The program may assume that the input is either a number or a one line string (that is, valid characters are [a-z][A-z][0-9] and spaces). If you adopt one of those restrictions, specify which in your answer.
- The program must use the entered input in some way. To put it more formally, the contents of the variable that takes the input must be used afterwards in some calculation that affects the final variable to be printed.

The winner will be the most upvoted solution.

Comment: `x/x for 1` doesn't work with `0/0`

Comment: The challenge is contradictory, if you say it has to affect the final variable to be printed, and meanwhile it has not. There is no way to get around that: If the input is the output, there is no influence.

Comment: After reading a comement to another post, I get another impression of the task: Fox input 7, output might be 7, and for input 8, output has to be 8 too, then? I thought in the beginning that we have to output the input.

Comment: +1, because when I first read the question I wanted to -1 and flag, but then I read the answers it provoked.

Answer (score 21):

**Python**

This question is boring.  I'd rather sleep.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(input())
```

Input a number.

Comment: So the output is... consistently... *nothing*?

Comment: @GigaWatt: yes indeed!  My guiding principal here was: ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer.  Honestly, I thought the question would be closed before I got any upvotes.

Answer (score 13):

### GolfScript

```
~{.3*){.2%}{2/}until.@=!}do
```

This program will take a positive integer as input, and will output `1` unless the input is a counterexample to the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).  While the Collatz conjecture remains an open problem, it is [known](http://www.ieeta.pt/~tos/3x+1.html) that there are no counterexamples below 5 × 2<sup>60</sup>.

Comment: Shouldn't it not halt for counterexamples. So really, it will always output 1.

Answer (score 11):

**Perl**

```
<>/0
```

produces for any input string:

```
Illegal division by zero at test5.pl line 1, <> line 1.
```

Comment: it's not code golf

Answer (score 11):

## Ruby

```
def a(x)
  4
end
```

I somehow felt [this](http://xkcd.com/221/) was related:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### Python

```
n=input()
p=37
print (n**p-n)%p
```

Takes an integer input, and always outputs 0.  Uses [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which states that n^p == n mod p.

Answer (score 7):

### J

```
=
```

Usage:

```
   =10
1
```

Always outputs 1.

Or how about an unhappy smiley verb:

```
{:0[
```

Usage:

```
   {:0[ 147
0
```

Always ouputs 0.

Comment: That's not what `=` does. You're thinking of `=~`. Practically (but not semantically) they're the same thing when your input is *one* integer.

Comment: @Eelvex Yes, I was thinking of `=~`. I've removed the incorrect bit from my answer.

Answer (score 5):

## C

This program reads an integer from stdin and then prints that integer, right?

```
main() {
    int i;
    printf("%d\n", scanf("%d", &i));
}
```

Well, no. It just prints `1`.

The input must be an integer though (otherwise it may output `0` or `-1`), which proves that the program "uses" the input.

Comment: um... isn't it UB to point to the argument space? For one, it's not possible with regcall.

Comment: Maybe. Then why would you use regcall?

Comment: Ok, on a (slighly) more serious note, I just used the argument because I'm lazy. Its use is besides the point really. I'll change it if it makes you happy.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript

```
var input = ~~prompt("Input an integer!");
if(Math.abs(input)<=Math.pow(2,31))
  console.log("It's too small! (not bigger than 2^31 = "+Math.pow(2,31)+")");
else console.log("It's quite big!");
```

Though JS can represent any integer between ±9,007,199,254,740,992, it will *always* print

> It's too small! (not bigger than 2^31 = 2147483648)

because bitwise operation is performed in range of 32bit.

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby:**

```
p !gets
```

Always outputs `false`. `gets` takes user input, `!` negates that and since strings are truthy, the result will be `false`.

Comment: What about empty strings?

Comment: @Timtech `p !"" #=> false`.

Comment: Hmm, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: What else did you expect? Everything in Ruby that's not `false` or `nil` is truthy, the empty string's no exception.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2

```
x=input()
print x^x
```

Only accepts integers. always outputs `0` by `xor`ing itself

Answer (score 3):

### APL

```
⍴⍣≡
```

`⍴` is the *shape* function, `⍴⍣≡` is the fixpoint of the shape function.

All APL values have a shape. Say, a 4x6x8 array has shape `4 6 8`; a scalar (like `3`) has shape `⍬` (no dimensions). Therefore, `⍴` always returns a one-dimensional list. This means that applying the output of `⍴` to `⍴` will always get you a one-dimensional list with one number in it. *That* means that applying `⍴` *again* will always get you a one-dimensional list with the number `1` in it.

Therefore, `⍴` converges to `1`; therefore `⍴⍣≡` will give `1` for all possible inputs.

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript

```
.=
```

Accepts any input and always prints `1`.

Comment: It doesn't really _use_ the input though.

Comment: @MrZander: Well, the criteria for what counts as using the input or not are quite vague. I'd say that if dividing by itself is OK, comparing to itself should also be fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Python**

```
def f(x):    
    return 0*x
```

Comment: `f(1e+300/1e-300)` returns `nan`.

Comment: You just blew my mind.

Comment: Thinking about it though, I guess that's ok: "valid characters are [a-z][A-z][0-9] and spaces", apparently floating point is out. So +1 for a simplistic yet working solution!

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
var input = prompt("Input something!");

console.log(new Number(input) === 1);
```

Will always return `false`, even with the input `1`

Answer (score 0):

### Golfscript (4 chars)

```
~1\?
```

Accepts an integer. Outputs 1.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl

```
$a=<>+1;for(1..length$a){$a=length$a}print$a
```

This program does use the input number, and it always prints 1.

Answer (score 0):

### Python

This one works for numbers only.
I can't prove that it works for all numbers (can anyone?), but it prints "False" for all cases I've tested.
EDIT: Fixed a bug in the last line.

```
p=lambda x:x>1 and (i*i>x for i in xrange(2,x+1) if x%i==0 or i*i>x).next()
q=lambda x:(i<x for i in xrange(2,x+1) if p(i) and p(x-i) or i==x).next()
x = input()
print x%2==0 and x>2 and not q(x)
```

Explanation (for those who think my Python code is unclear):
`p(x)` tells you if x is a prime.
`q(x)` looks for two primes, whose some is x.
The program prints True if the number is even, greater than 2 and not the sum of 2 primes.
Please tell me if you find such a number.

Comment: We probably won't find such a number: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture

Comment: I was about to say 4, but then I thought, 2 is prime :)

Answer (score 0):

### Python

```
print float("inf")*sum(map(ord,raw_input()))
```

Always returns 'infinity'.

Answer (score 0):

## Q

Returns 1. Where no parameters are declared, Q implicitly uses x,y& z where appropriate. I think this satisfies the second condition...

```
{1}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python

`print input()*0`

Answer (score 0):

### C

Produces 1 (prints and returns) for every input. (Input being the number of command line args)

```
j;main(c){j=0;while(c){j+=c%2;c/=2;}return j^1?main(j):printf("%d",j);}
```

This program does the same `#error 1` but cannot properly speaking be said to take input (unless you count the rest of the program after as input).

Answer (score 0):

## Python

```
print eval('42#'+raw_input())
```

Accepts any input

Answer (score 0):

## PostScript

This function takes one argument of any type, actively discards, and will always output `­`, unless you didn't supply it with enough arguments (which I am going to define as being undefined behavior for this function), depending on the value of the argument. Here is its implementation:

```
/f {pop} def
```

This function will always take one more argument than is currently on the stack, so it will always output a `stackunderflow` error, depending on the input.

```
/f {clear pop} def
```

And here is a third, even more useful function, which I will define as having undefined behavior, depending on the number, types, and values of the arguments.  Here is its implementation:

```
­
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp

```
(unless (read))
```

Always returns nil (unless you crash it with stupid input)

Answer (score 0):

### Brainf**k

Since the question is self-contradictory it's hard to give a serious answer, so here it is:

```
,[[->+<],]>[<->+<+>--<+>][->+>+[-]>+>+<<<<][->-<]+>[<->[-]]>[->--<----]+>[[---<->+<+>-]<->]>>[+>-<--]+>[[-]<->]<<[->-<-->+++>>>>>+<<<->+<<<+++++[>>++++++<<]]+>[<+>-]++>+<-<->>>>+<<<<->+<+>->>>[<]>[>]<[<[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<]+[>+>+>+>+<<---<<[-]]>>++<<[>>+[+<<<-]>>-<[<]+<<[<<->+]]>[->>+<<]>>[->+<]>[>+++++++++++<-]>[->+>+>+<<<]>[.>]
```

Accepts any string or number as input, always outputs "!!!". Have fun figuring out what it does.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure

```
(and(read-line)0)
```

Crudely equivalent to the prior common lisp submission, except that it makes no attempt to ensure that the line "read" is valid in any way shape or form. Compiled or interpreted, this program will read a single line and exit 0 in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

### Game Maker Language

```
if argument0 return argument0/argument0 else return argument0
```

It can be any script, just call `script(argument)` - it returns `true` if the number is not 0, else it returns `false`

If this was code golf, it would be `if argument0 a=1 return a` which is **25 characters** when compiled with the option "Treat all uninitialized variables as value 0".

Comment: I forgot to add, the input must be a number.

Answer (score 0):

## C++

Accepts any input.  Prints ASCII equivalent of each character entered:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s;
  cout << "Enter a string: ";
  cin >> s;

  cout << "ASCII characters of input:\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    cout << s[i] << ": " << int(s[i]) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge

```
&@
```

always returns nothing.

---

And a less pointless version:

```
&>:v
 -
 ^1_.@
```

Always returns 0